# What is %n in printf and how to use it?

Tags: c++, c, printf

What is %n in printf?

How to use it in my codes (with a sample code please)?

Thanks.

**Edit**:

After googling I couldn't found any sample about %n. But some people close this question without an answer.

Comment: `man 3 printf` And a witty comment so that the minimum comment length is met.

Comment: @pmr: Could you link to a page that have a sample about %n?

Comment: We really need that "General Reference" close reason.

Comment: How is this not a valid question? I think a usage example could be really informative.

Comment: @Amir: Not sure what you googled, but `google -> printf c++` yields http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ as the first result, and that describes what %n is for.

Comment: As a sidenote: I mistakenly voted for re-open and can't reverse my vote. But I am really neutral on whether to close or open this one.

Comment: @phresnel: I said: "couldn't found any sample". I could not found any sample code.

Answer (score 3):

The `%n` specifier does not print anything and the corresponding argument must be a pointer to signed integer where the number of characters written so far is stored.

Source [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Not _should_, **must**. Not signed pointer, but pointer to signed. Fixed for you.

Comment: @phresnel Thanks, that was my mistake. Typed it in a hurry. Yes it must be a pointer to a signed int.